# Reset form in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I have the following problem:

I have a form where I am modifying data, and I have a button to reset on my form:
clean radio buttons, checkbox and fields

I am using the following code:

```
$ ("reset"). click (function () {
        $ ("form"). trigger ("reset") ;/ / clean fields
        $ ("input: radio"). removeAttr ("checked") ;/ / clean radio buttons
        $ ('input: checkbox'). removeAttr ('checked');/ / checkbox limpis
        $ ('form [action = "{posturl}"]') [0]. reset ();
        $ ('# formid'). reset ();
});
```

This works fine for Chrome and Firefox browsers, but not IE.

I need to do the same but for IE. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Do you mean: $(':reset') ?

Comment: Aren't you resetting things you might not want to reset? You might want some things checked by default. If $('form').trigger('reset') worked it would clear every form on the page, which might not be desired. Simply putting in an <input type="reset"> and leaving it alone would probably be better than this.